# Where do you find custom ev3 code blocks?

Tags: ev3

I've heard of people using custom-made ev3 (*code*) blocks in the software, but I don't know where to look for them. Can someone post relevant links? Specifically, I am looking for more technical blocks like one to get the character at some index in a string (the second character of "hello" is "e") as I am used to real text coding and the block coding editor is rather... lacking for my needs. Thanks in advance!